# I like comparison query between two MariaDB tables based on timespamt differs

Tags: mariadb

I have two tables. First 'check' contains user_id and timestamp. The second 'passing' contains the same user_id little different timestamp and direction. Sometimes the second table not contains data.
I like to see user_id, time1, time2, direction. The different between time1 and time2 is max 10 seconds.
First table:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id | time                |
+---------+---------------------+
|       3 | 2023-10-25 09:29:43 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 09:28:39 |
|       5 | 2023-10-25 09:19:33 |
|       8 | 2023-10-25 09:18:46 |
|       9 | 2023-10-25 09:17:19 |
|      17 | 2023-10-25 09:16:46 |
|      18 | 2023-10-25 09:16:31 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 09:15:46 |
|      16 | 2023-10-25 09:11:53 |
|      20 | 2023-10-25 09:07:53 |
|      20 | 2023-10-25 09:02:31 |
|       8 | 2023-10-25 09:02:25 |
|      17 | 2023-10-25 09:00:53 |
|       5 | 2023-10-25 09:00:49 |
|      18 | 2023-10-25 09:00:43 |
|      16 | 2023-10-25 09:00:28 |
|       9 | 2023-10-25 09:00:24 |
|      22 | 2023-10-25 09:00:16 |
|      22 | 2023-10-25 08:58:09 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 08:49:46 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

Second table:

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| user_id | time                | direction |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
|      14 | 2023-10-25 09:28:42 |         1 |
|       8 | 2023-10-25 09:18:49 |         1 |
|      17 | 2023-10-25 09:16:49 |         1 |
|      18 | 2023-10-25 09:16:34 |         1 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 09:15:46 |         0 |
|      16 | 2023-10-25 09:11:55 |         1 |
|      20 | 2023-10-25 09:02:31 |         0 |
|       8 | 2023-10-25 09:02:25 |         0 |
|      17 | 2023-10-25 09:00:53 |         0 |
|       5 | 2023-10-25 09:00:49 |         0 |
|      18 | 2023-10-25 09:00:43 |         0 |
|      16 | 2023-10-25 09:00:28 |         0 |
|       9 | 2023-10-25 09:00:24 |         0 |
|      22 | 2023-10-25 09:00:19 |         1 |
|      22 | 2023-10-25 08:58:09 |         0 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 08:49:49 |         1 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 08:47:53 |         0 |
|       2 | 2023-10-25 08:46:53 |         1 |
|       2 | 2023-10-25 08:44:54 |         0 |
|       4 | 2023-10-25 08:32:14 |         0 |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+
```

What is the simplest sql query?

I tried INNER JOIN with TIMESTAMPDIFF, but I got entry for all fields:

`SELECT check.user_id, check.time, passing.time, passing.direction FROM check LEFT JOIN passing ON check.user_id = passing.user_id AND  TIMESTAMPDIFF (SECOND, check.time, passing.time) < 10;`

The result what I need:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| user_id | time                | time                | direction |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|       3 | 2023-10-25 09:29:43 |                     |           |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 09:28:39 | 2023-10-25 09:28:42 |         1 |
|       5 | 2023-10-25 09:19:33 |                     |           |
|       8 | 2023-10-25 09:18:46 | 2023-10-25 09:18:49 |         1 |
|       9 | 2023-10-25 09:17:19 |                     |           |
|      17 | 2023-10-25 09:16:46 | 2023-10-25 09:16:49 |         1 |
|      18 | 2023-10-25 09:16:31 | 2023-10-25 09:16:34 |         1 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 09:15:46 | 2023-10-25 09:15:46 |         0 |
|      16 | 2023-10-25 09:11:53 | 2023-10-25 09:11:55 |         1 |
|      20 | 2023-10-25 09:07:53 |                     |           |
|      20 | 2023-10-25 09:02:31 | 2023-10-25 09:02:31 |         0 |
|       8 | 2023-10-25 09:02:25 | 2023-10-25 09:02:25 |         0 |
|      17 | 2023-10-25 09:00:53 | 2023-10-25 09:00:53 |         0 |
|       5 | 2023-10-25 09:00:49 | 2023-10-25 09:00:49 |         0 |
|      18 | 2023-10-25 09:00:43 | 2023-10-25 09:00:43 |         0 |
|      16 | 2023-10-25 09:00:28 | 2023-10-25 09:00:28 |         0 |
|       9 | 2023-10-25 09:00:24 | 2023-10-25 09:00:24 |         0 |
|      22 | 2023-10-25 09:00:16 | 2023-10-25 09:00:19 |         1 |
|      22 | 2023-10-25 08:58:09 | 2023-10-25 08:58:09 |         0 |
|      14 | 2023-10-25 08:49:46 | 2023-10-25 08:49:49 |         1 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIMESTAMPDIFF` can return negative values that are `< 10` and your join will match rows from different entries

If you know that `passing.time >= check.time`, then you can use

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, check.time, passing.time) BETWEEN 0 and 10
```

Otherwise you should use either

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, check.time, passing.time) BETWEEN -10 and 10
```

or

```
ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, check.time, passing.time)) < 10
```

Note that neither of the obove can use an index. However that should not be a problem, if there are not many entries per user. But if you'd want to use an index on `passing(user_id, time)` you could use

```
LEFT JOIN passing 
  ON  passing.user_id = check.user_id
  AND passing.time    BETWEEN 
    check.time - INTERVAL 10 SECOND  AND 
    check.time + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, this solution makes me closer.